# When I try to run the command "nest new project name" I got this message error: Error not found node:fs

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, nest, node.js-fs

I'm creating a new NestJS project, but when I try to run the NestJS command "nest new project name" I'm facing the following problem:

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUVb.png)

I tryied to update my versions of node, npm, angular-devkit, and uninstall the NestJS and install again.. but it doesn't work.

Comment: this must be an issue with your nodejs version. Which version are you using? run `node -v`

Comment: It wasn't my node version, but it was a node problem, I solved this problem by uninstalling my node and installing again. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.